# Finding minimum difference between a pair of integers

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, integer, minimum

Given the set of unsorted integers, how to find every pair of integers which have minimum difference. There are 3 samples as described below:

```
a = random.sample (range(-200,200), 5)
b = random.sample (range(-1000, 1000), 25)
c = random.sample (range(-2000, 2000), 50)
```

The expected output should be something like:

```
List A = [-85, -154, -33, 192, -160]

Minimum pairs for list A:
(-160, -154)
```

Comment: Without doing your homework for you, I'd try sorting the array.

Comment: Hi, please add more details to the questions. In its present state it is hard to understand the requirement, can you please add an example to illustrate the requirement?

Comment: @Aravind What is not clear?

Comment: Now, that the question is edited, I understand, so you are looking for the pair having the minimum difference. As EOF has suggested, sorting would help you. Sort the list and check the difference between consecutive elements.

Comment: @Aravind I simply rolled the question edit back, I don't understand why OP removed the explanation.

Comment: If the array values are not unique there may be several equal values, which would need several pairs to answer the question. Even if the values are unique, there may be several pairs with the same minimum difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Pair
{
    size_t first;
    size_t second;
};

struct Pair minimum_difference( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    struct Pair p = { 0 };

    if ( 1 < n )
    {
        p.first = 0;
        p.second = 1;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
            {
//              printf( "%d %d %llu\n", a[i], a[j], 
//                      ( unsigned long long )abs( a[i] - a[j] ) );
                if ( ( unsigned long long )abs( a[i] - a[j] ) <
                     ( unsigned long long )abs( a[p.first] - a[p.second] ) )
                {
                    p.first  = i;
                    p.second = j;
                }                  
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    const int UPPER_BOUND = 40 * N;

    int a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % ( 2 * UPPER_BOUND ) - UPPER_BOUND;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    struct Pair p = minimum_difference( a, N );

    printf( "(%d, %d)\n", a[p.first], a[p.second] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look loke

```
119 9 -193 21 -43 
(9, 21)
```

This prpgram finds only the first pair with the minimum difference. If there are several pairs with the minimum difference when you have to allocate dynamically an array of pairs. Of course the function will be changed.

The other approach is to use a sort-copy algorithm by using an additional array. And then traverse this array calculating the difference.

Comment: The list is random integers

Comment: @diplodocus And what is the problem? Fill the array with random numbers.

Comment: the list is supposed to generate its own random numbers and the program should find the minimum pair from that list of random numbers.

Comment: what do you think would be the big-o complexity for this?

Comment: @diplodocus It has complexity O( n^2)

Comment: Casting `( unsigned long long )` _after_ `abs()` serves questionable purposes.  If `a[i] - a[j]` overflows, rest of code is undefined behavior.  Make more send to do `llabs((long long) a[i] - a[j])`

Comment: @chux I even do not remember why I used such a casting.:) It seems that it would be indeed enough to use llabs as you showed.